# "docker build" executes powershell script wrong way

Tags: docker-for-windows

I'm trying to create a docker image with openssl DLLs, but something goes wrong.
Before I build, I have following folder structure on my PC:

```
/docker-sandbox
├── deployment/
│   ├── libeay32.dll (OpenSSL)
│   ├── ssleay32.dll (OpenSSL)
│   └── deployment.ps1
└── Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

COPY deployment/ C:/deployment

RUN "powershell C:\deployment\deployment.ps1"
```

And I have the powershell script:

```
#go to corrext location
Set-Location C:\deployment

#locate openssl libraries
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:\openssllib
Move-Item -Path '.\libeay32.dll' -Destination 'C:\openssllib\libeay32.dll'
Move-Item -Path '.\ssleay32.dll' -Destination 'C:\openssllib\ssleay32.dll'
```

After I execute "docker build ." in the docker-sandbox folder, I start the container with following command:

```
docker run -i $IMAGE_ID powershell
```

But the C:\openssllib folder in the container is empty (and there are also no OpenSSL DLLs in the "deployment" folder). Why? 
When I remove RUN from the dockerfile and execute "deployment.ps1" in the container by hand, openssl DLLs are located in the right place. What is the reason for such behavior?

Comment: Use RUN dir c:\\deployment immediately after COPY and you will know if you files are actually coped into container image

Comment: @GregorySuvalian, thanks for suggestion, I've done this and after COPY OpenSSL DLLs are in the directory!

Comment: So if you build container and then use `docker exec` into it there is no files in that folder  or what is the issue?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian yes, my issue is that DLLs are copied, but after execution of "deployment.ps1" there are no(!) DLLs in the container.

Comment: I don't see anything in your powershell which will delete files from that folder but start with empty powershell file and add line by line to script to find out which specific line is causing it.